# In jqplot are stacked candlesticks possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, jqplot

Are stacked candlestick graphs possible in jqplot? I know this is quite a misuse of them but I need a to be able to specify a start and end point for multiple entries on the y axis at the same point on the x axis. I've tried stacked bar graphs and it looks like I cant specify the start and end points of the data like I can with the candlesticks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, apparently they are.  I used the sample code from here.
[Candlestick Chart Sample](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/candlestick-charts.php)

and added stackSeries:true, seriesColors: ["red", "green"], and doubled up the series: line to

series: [{renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true}},{renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true}}]

and doubled up the series. $.jqplot('chart1',[ohlc,ohlc]